# The number of videos captured is different from the number returned by the API

Tags: youtube-api

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
id = UC25QkYYCp8VjZzMh8hUR-2g
part = snippet,statistics
```

The page displays 51 videos
The page displays 49 videos

why？？？？？

```json
  "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "2317575",
    "subscriberCount": "9210",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "49"
  }
```

[image]